# How does stale-while-revalidate interact with s-maxage in Cache-Control header?

Tags: caching, next.js, server-side-rendering

Just want to know around the header that I have specified for my SSR pages: `public, s-maxage=3600, stale-while-revalidate=59`.

Please note that my `stale-while-revalidate` value is 59 seconds which is way less than `s-maxage` value which is 1 hour. I want to know that when `stale-while-revalidate` value is smaller than `s-maxage`, what happens exactly? Is the `stale-while-revalidate` header ignored?

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by [@DanilaVershinin in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77641710/1870780), `s-maxage` and `stale-while-revalidate` are applied to different caches - shared cache and browser cache respectively. They do not overlap with each other.

---

**Disclaimer:** this answer applies to `max-age` (and not `s-maxage`).

Setting the page's `Cache-Control` header to `max-age=3600, stale-while-revalidate=59` means two things:

1. The page is considered fresh for 3600 seconds (`max-age=3600`);
2. The page will continue to be served from stale up to 59 seconds after that (`stale-while-revalidate=59`) while revalidation is done in the background.

`stale-while-revalidate` does not get ignored, it determines the extra time window when revalidation occurs after the page's `max-age` has passed (i.e. when the page is stale).

Here's the cache states across the three time windows (based on https://web.dev/stale-while-revalidate/#live-example):

| 0 to 3600s | 3601s to 3660s | After 3660s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cached page is *fresh* and used to serve the page. No revalidation. | Cached page is *stale* but used to serve the page. Revalidation occurs in the background to populate cache. | Cached page is *stale* and not used at all. New request is made to serve the page and populate cache. |

---

Excerpt from the [HTTP Cache-Control Extensions for Stale Content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5861#section-3.1) spec:

> Generally, servers will want to set the combination of `max-age` and
> `stale-while-revalidate` to the longest total potential freshness
> lifetime that they can tolerate.  For example, with both set to 600,
> the server must be able to tolerate the response being served from
> cache for up to 20 minutes.
>
> Since asynchronous validation will only happen if a request occurs
> after the response has become stale, but before the end of the
> `stale-while-revalidate` window, the size of that window and the
> likelihood of a request during it determines how likely it is that all
> requests will be served without delay.  If the window is too small, or
> traffic is too sparse, some requests will fall outside of it, and
> block until the server can validate the cached response.

Comment: once a stale-while-invalidate fires, and gets a "fresh" page.. does the process start all over again? Meaning, that "new" page now has 3600 to be served from cache before a "new" page is generated?

Comment: @jamesemanon Yes, that's correct. The new page gets cached for another 3600s.

Comment: The answer is largely based on what would happen if `max-age` (and not `s-maxage`) was used. With `s-maxage` this timeline won't happen. Please see my answer.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in for performance researches out there. `s-maxage` "nulls" the effect of `stale-while-revalidate` in shared proxies. In other words, there is no background validation and serving stale content by shared cache.

So while they do both work (`s-maxage` applies to shared and `stale-while-revalidate` will apply at browser), the expectation that you have stale while revalidate setup in shared cache is incorrect. There are no background updates done by shared cache.

From [RFC 9111 HTTP Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111):

> The s-maxage directive incorporates the semantics of the proxy‑revalidate response directive (Section 5.2.2.8) for a shared cache. A shared cache MUST NOT reuse a stale response with s-maxage to satisfy another request until it has been successfully validated by the origin, as defined by Section 4.3.

To answer question as is, no, these cache lifetimes will not even overlap because they are applied to different caches.

Comment: The section of the RFC you've copied is referring to proxy-revalidate which is not the same as stale-while-revalidate. I don't think this applies and that it is valid for s-maxage and stale-while-revalidate to be used concurrently.